# Bigquery Datetime timestamp function

Tags: google-bigquery

Can Anyone Explain me the code below

```
DATETIME(TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(created_time_epoch), "America/Texas"),
created_time_epoch,
DATE(TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(pickup_time_epoch)),
```

How to incorporate these changes to GCP using DATA PREP ?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to replicate a function from some SQL query into some Data Prep recipes?

From the BigQuery side, I can explain what the code is doing, then I think you could figure out what do use from DataPrep to replicate it, as I am not particularly familiar with it.

1- `TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(x)` takes the value of `x`, which assumes is an integer representing a timestamp in [UNIX-seconds](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/) (example, 1586872288), and converts it into a Timestamp ('2020-04-14 13:51:28+00:00).

2- `DATETIME(y)` converts what you have as `y` into a [DateTime](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#datetime_type). Think of it as a slightly different way to represent a TIMESTAMP.

What these two things together are doing is converting your `created_time_epoch` into its equivalent DATETIME in the America/Texas timezone.

3- Similarly, `DATE(z)` converts your integer into a Date field.

Same thing, converting your `pickup_time_epoch` integer into a DATE.

Very straightforward stuff.

As for how to implement it in DataPrep, basically [this](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/UNIXTIMEFORMAT-Function_57344709) is what you need. 
Just convert `created_time_epoch` and `pickup_time_epoch` into the stuff you need using that UNIXTIMEFORMAT and the format you want to use.

Probably this is a good example of an equivalency.

`DATE(TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(pickup_time_epoch)))` [SQL] = `unixtimeformat(pickup_time_epoch,'yyyy-MM-dd')` [DataPrep]

Comment: Francesco , I have done my part of converting the integer into date . The main issue is timezone how to bring it into UTC and than probably in my time zone. Is there any way i can see my own timezone on which dataprep is running ?  for ex  1586050147-  2020-04-05·01:04:000·The former number is converted to date but now i do not know which timezone it is and can i change into UTC and further more to my own timezone . Your help would be much appreciated

Comment: All UNIX timestamps are in UTC mate, meaning that all your DATE, DATETIME and TIMESTAMPS are in UTC already. Now, to change it to your own timezone you could use DATE_ADD or something similar.

Comment: I don't understand why are you sharing those results, is there anything on this question you still need help with?. For any extra steps out of the scope of this I do recommend you creating a new question and solving this one.